# Example of a "CLOSE" netstat state

Tags: c, linux, sockets, netstat

`man netstat` says that `CLOSE` is one of `netstat`'s states:

> CLOSE  The socket is not being used.

I have created a program in `C` that creates a socket that does not do anything using the following code:

```
int main()
{
    // Create socket
    int s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    // Pause the program
    getchar();
}
```

I have run my program, and then run the command `netstat -a -p`, but I did not see my program with a `CLOSE` state (I did not see my program at all).

How can I create a socket that `netstat` will display with a `CLOSE` state?

Comment: Off-topic: check the return value of socket s, does it created the socket or not? `if s < 0 {...}`?

Comment: @LethalProgrammer Return value is `3` (success).

Comment: Creating a socket only allocates a file handle. You need to call bind().

Comment: @stark Even after `bind()`, the socket was still not present in `netstat`'s results.

Comment: Did you call either listen (server) or connect (client)?

Comment: @stark No, if I call listen or connect, then the state will not be `CLOSE` anymore.

Comment: You could try calling listen and then close, but if there has never been a connection then that may not work.

Comment: @stark I have closed the socket after binding and listening, but still not showing in `netstat` (I think `close()` deallocates the socket from memory all together, so it doesn't make sense to be showed in `netstat`).